# Expand command not working

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I am trying to convert all tabs to spaces using expand command.

Command:    `cat department.txt`

Output :

```
1           QA 
2           DEV
3           OPS
```

On executing expand department.txt; the output is still same.

I have verified that my file contains tab characters by using od -c. Can someone explain why expand is not working ?

> UPDATE: As muru pointed out in below comment; I was having wrong
>   expectations from expand command, i was expecting tabs to be converted
>   to single space; which caused the confusion. Expand command converts
>   tab to equivalent spaces.

Comment: And have you verified that the output of `expand` has no tab characters?

Comment: I am sorry. I was having wrong expectations. I was expecting tabs to be converted to be single space. On checking od -c on the output of expand i noticed tabs have been converted to equivalent spaces. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert tabs to single spaces each, you can still use `expand`, with tabstops set to 1 instead of the default 8:

```
$ expand foo
1       QA
2       DEV
3       OPS
$ expand -t1 foo
1 QA
2 DEV
3 OPS
```

However, this still expands consecutive tabs to individual spaces:

```
$ vim foo
$ expand foo
1               QA
2               DEV
3               OPS
$ expand -t1 foo
1  QA
2  DEV
3  OPS
```

Depending on the behaviour you want, you can use that or `tr`:

```
$ tr -s '\t' ' ' < foo
1 QA
2 DEV
3 OPS
```

Comment: Since tr provides the feature of both squeezing and individual replace, why would one ever create a command like expand ? To me it just looks like a wrapper over tr without squeeze argument. Or am i missing something ?

Comment: @linuxuser well, how would you replace a tab with n spaces (n depending on which column you're currently in) using `tr`?

Comment: Was going through tr documentation. And below option is specified but i tried its not working `[CHAR*REPEAT]`. I tried `tr '\t' '[ *5]' <file.txt`. Do you know whats the use of this option ?

Comment: @linuxuser try `echo aeioubfgh | tr 'aeiou' '[c*3]d'` and see if that makes sense to you.

Comment: Yes makes sense. so to answer your above question. yes it cannot be achieved via tr. for which one can use expand/unexpand command always.